# Refreshing data in Google Maps only when map moved by certain distance (to save calls)

Tags: google-maps

I have a google maps application which displays markers based on data (lat,lon). As the user moves the map I have to refresh the data and show new points.

Now I am wondering to minimize the calls to the db, is there a way to refresh the data only if the map moved by certain % of the total span distance (ex: 15%). For example current maps show a distance of 1000km span, refresh the data only if the map moves horizontal/vertical by at least 150km.

Comment: Yes, there is and it is fairly easy, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: I got the distance between left and right columns saved them as old. At moveend got new coords and calculated distance moved. Now based on zoom level I can decide whether to call or not. This approach falls apart (some what) when the user tries diagonal move... so wondering there got to be a better way of doing this.

Comment: @user1587722 i too have similar requirement. if you solved this, can you please help me with solution.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how the variable *pixelThreshold* is used on [**this old V2 mashup**](http://maps.forum.nu/server_side_clusterer/). It does the same thing but it works in all directions because in the moveend event handler I compare the distance between the map center before and after the move.

That is an API V2 application but it should be easy to apply the same strategy to a V3 application.

Comment: OK this is what I did - got span across the map, then multiplied by 0.1 to get 10%. Now every moveend if the distance moved is > 0.1*span then only I refreshed. Looks working.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "got span across the map", but if the answer was useful to you please feel free to upvote it and eventually accept it.